# webdriverio browser.execute returns null

Tags: javascript, meteor, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have a meteor app and want to retrieve some data inside a unit test from the client via a headless browser from webdriver.io.

The data I want is from this function:

`Session.get()` -> http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/sessions/

The headless browser I use is from below URL:

http://webdriver.io/

My test looks like this:

```
describe('[Check Boards]', () => {
  it('should exist', () => {
    const board = browser.execute('Session.get(\'currentBoard\')');
    ...
  }
}
```

When i run this command `Session.get('currentBoard')` inside a real browser console, I get the board as expected.

But when I run it from the code like described above inside a mocha test, I get this result:

```
{
  "state": "success",
  "sessionId": "12345",
  "hCode": 12345,
  "value": null,
  "class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response",
  "_status": 0
}
```

The value is null, but there should be the board.

Comment: This code is not enough to understand your problem and help you. What is the `Board`? Where/when is it initialized? When your example code is running?

Comment: Hello i have changed the code a bit, and tried to supplement some missing parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`browser.execute` expects a function to run in the browser. You're passing in a string, so it probably doesn't know what to do. Here's an updated code snippet that should work:

```
describe('[Check Boards]', () => {
  it('should exist', () => {
    const board = browser.execute(function () {
      return Session.get('currentBoard');
    });
    ...
  }
}
```